# OnBackPressed duplicate list is adding in android for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi in the below on back press from one fragment to current fragement duplicate list got creating using recyclerview in android.

If I am load my fragment it is giving me correct response.but moving to next fragment and coming back to current fragment .when I am coming back to the current fragment it is showing duplicate list in and not closing app.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements ViewAppointmentAdapter.SelectIemClickListner,ViewAppointmentAdapter.StartSelectIemClickListner,DoctorAdapter.SelectIemClickListner, SpeclializationAdapter.MyItemClickListener, PatientAdapter.SelectIemClickListner,DoctorPatientListAdapter.SelectIemClickListner,DoctorPatientListAdapter.StartSelectIemClickListner,ViewAppointmentAdapter.SelectIemCancelClickListner {
public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((NavigationViewActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Home");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);
 data_viewpatientlists = new ArrayList<>();
        viewpatientdataLists = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerAppointmentlist = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerAppointmentlist);
        recyclerAppointmentlist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        viewAppointmentAdapter = new ViewAppointmentAdapter(requireContext(), data_viewpatientlists, this, this, this);
data_viewpatientlists.clear();
                            viewPatientList();
}
 private void viewPatientList() {

//        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
//        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
//        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
//        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
//        progressDialog.show();

        String RegistrationNo = LoginId;
        final APIService service = RetroClass.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIService.class);
        Call<Patient_ViewPatientlist> call = service.ViewPatientList(RegistrationNo);
        Log.wtf("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Patient_ViewPatientlist>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Patient_ViewPatientlist> call, Response<Patient_ViewPatientlist> response) {
                Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                    Patient_ViewPatientlist patient_patientlist = response.body();
                    viewpatientdataLists = patient_patientlist.getData();
                    for (Data_Viewpatientlist view_patientList : viewpatientdataLists) {
                        String First_name = view_patientList.getFName();
                        String last_name = view_patientList.getLName();
                        String SlotFrom = view_patientList.getSlotFrom();
                        String SlotTo = view_patientList.getSlotTo();
                        String FromDate = view_patientList.getForDate();
                        String booking_id = view_patientList.getBookingId();
                        String doct_id = view_patientList.getDocId();
                        String profile_photo = view_patientList.getProfllePhoto();
                        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

                        Date date = null;
                        try {
                            date = inputFormat.parse(FromDate);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String outputDateStr = outputFormat.format(date);
                        Data_Viewpatientlist data_doctorpatientlist = new Data_Viewpatientlist(booking_id, First_name, last_name, outputDateStr, SlotFrom, SlotTo);
                        data_viewpatientlists.add(data_doctorpatientlist);
                        Log.d("data_viewpatientlists", String.valueOf(data_viewpatientlists.size()));
                        recyclerAppointmentlist.setAdapter(viewAppointmentAdapter);

                        viewAppointmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                //   progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Patient_ViewPatientlist> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("error", t.getMessage());
                //  progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked deeply, but it looks like you are clearing the list of the passed adapter only when you create your fragment.

When you return to the previous fragment, the onCreateView is not called, it is called fragment method onAttach.

Try to override the onAttach method and clear the list there.

Comment: Where should add onAttach method in current fragment or next fragment

Comment: See here Fragment's lifecycle https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle

you need to paste on the first fragment next override method:

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    // Code here (clearing and other things)
}

Method onAttach of superclass calls, but we don't see it

Comment: small querry if I am moving previous to current fragment how to make the same content

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

first of all clear a data of 'recyclerAppointmentlist' in onResponse() and then add the new records

it looks like this:

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<Patient_ViewPatientlist>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Patient_ViewPatientlist> call, Response<Patient_ViewPatientlist> response) {
            Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                viewpatientdataLists.clear()
                Patient_ViewPatientlist patient_patientlist = response.body();
                viewpatientdataLists = patient_patientlist.getData();
```